# EAI_AGAIN error in Node JS server when connecting to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongoose, amazon-ec2, mongodb-atlas

I got the following error from the server today:

```
    { MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/home/ubuntu/xxx-v.1-backend/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:897:9)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
  name: 'MongoTimeoutError',
  reason:
   { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN xyz.mongodb.net xyz.mongodb.net:27017
       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
     name: 'MongoNetworkError',
     errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
     [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

The server was running fine for more than a year, and all of a sudden, the server stopped working today. When I checked into the EC2 AWS Monitoring chart, it mentioned that CPU utilization is 100%. So, I rebooted the server from the EC2 console. Once the server restarted, when I looked into logs, I found the above error repeated multiple times. So, I assume that the NodeJS might have attempted to connect to Atlas multiple times and hence the CPU utilization being 100%.

When I looked up online for the EAI_AGAIN error, they mentioned that IP address might not be added to MongoDB Atlas or the name given is wrong. I checked both the suggestions, and the result is these are not the issue.

I do not know how to proceed further. Please assist with this issue.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I have the same problem. IP whitelisted on the Atlas MongoDB service, ports opened on my server (even disabled the UFW when trying). Still having the same issue.

Comment: One possible issue might be number of connections with mongodb atlas might have exceeded the limit. @JohnF I haven't figured this issue yet.